# How to duplicate/automate orders at a workshop?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I need to make 7 beds for my dwarfs, but I had to setup manually every order in the Carpenter's Workshop.

It should be possible to duplicate order or setup a certain number of desired items after creating a task.

Answer (score 1):

The "Work orders" tab in the workshop panel is what I was looking for, and **it requires a Manager**.

To assign a Manager, open the nobles and administrator menu (press `n`) and assign a proficient dwarf to the Manager position.

After doing so, the "Work orders" tab won't warn you about the need for a manager and will allow you to create work orders.

Here's how to order 7 beds:

1. Create a work order.
2. Select "Make bed."
3. Click the "#" button and enter the desired number: 7.
4. Click the "<>=!=" condition button and repeatedly click on the clock button to change the frequency to "One-time order."
5. You can exit the menu; the order is now set.

Comment: For additional fun, you can set conditionals on your work order to respawn the "Make 7 beds" order whenever there are less than 10 beds and more than 20 logs (for example)

Comment: Yes, I started to understood the manager panel a bit better and found the suggested conditions coupled with "check every X" very powerful !